# Display SPL level in numeric value rather than varying colour intensity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-audio, avaudiosession

I am trying to develop an SPL meter for a uni project within iOS, I have been following an online tutorial on how to get audio input and display the input level, however this tutorial shows the input as a varying intensity of colour and also at the RMS value, not the peak. I have found two previous posts relating to this however they aren't informative enough to help, and being a newbie to stack overflow I am unable to ask for further support on the answers provided.

[Previous Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230854/ios-detect-blow-into-mic-and-convert-the-results-swift)

[Previous Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929989/how-to-monitor-audio-input-on-ios-using-swift-example)

The project tutorial I have been following is running in Objective-C rather than Swift as it is an old video collection, however it does (almost) what I need it to so have not tried to change to swift, until I understand what I'm doing and why I'm doing it.

Here is the whole code for the recording and input level monitoring:

```
//Lynda.Com Tutorial Project


#import "ViewController.h"

@import AudioToolbox;
@import AVFoundation;

#define kOutputBus 0
#define kInputBus 1

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIView *indicatorView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

static AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self setupAudio];
}

- (void) setupAudio {
    AudioComponentDescription desc;

    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    OSStatus status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &audioUnit);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSAssert(status == noErr,@"Error");
    }

    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;

    audioFormat.mSampleRate = 44100.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(SInt16);
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket * audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame;

    UInt32 flag = 1;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, kInputBus, &flag, sizeof(flag));
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSAssert(status == noErr,@"Error");
    }

    flag = 0;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, kOutputBus, &flag, sizeof(flag));
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSAssert(status == noErr,@"Error");
    }

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit , kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, kInputBus, &audioFormat, sizeof(audioFormat));
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSAssert(status == noErr,@"Error");
    }

    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit , kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, kInputBus, &callbackStruct, sizeof(callbackStruct));
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSAssert(status == noErr,@"Error");
    }

    status = AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSAssert(status == noErr,@"Error");
    }

}

static OSStatus recordingCallback(

                                  void *inRefCon,
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData

                            ) {

    AudioBuffer buffer;

    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * sizeof(SInt16);
    buffer.mData = malloc(buffer.mDataByteSize);

    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;

    OSStatus status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit , ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, &bufferList);
    if (status != noErr) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    SInt16 *frameBuffer = buffer.mData;

    double totalAmplitude = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; i++) {
        //printf("%i\n",frameBuffer[i]);
        totalAmplitude += frameBuffer[i] * frameBuffer[i];
    }

    totalAmplitude /= inNumberFrames;

    totalAmplitude = sqrt(totalAmplitude);

    float alphaFloat = totalAmplitude / (float)SHRT_MAX * 2;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ViewController *viewController = (__bridge ViewController*)inRefCon;
        viewController.indicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:alphaFloat];
    });

    return noErr;
}

- (IBAction)recordButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSError *error;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSAssert(error == nil, @"Error");
    }
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSAssert(error == nil, @"Error");
    }

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
            OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStart(audioUnit);
            if (status != noErr) {
                NSAssert(status == noErr,@"Error");
            }
        } else {
            NSAssert(NO, @"Error");
        }
    }];
}

- (IBAction)stopButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStop(audioUnit);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSAssert(status == noErr,@"Error");
    }
    NSError *error;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSAssert(error == nil, @"Error");
    }
    self.indicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) dealloc {
    OSStatus status = AudioComponentInstanceDispose(audioUnit);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSAssert(status == noErr,@"Error");
    }
}

@end
```

What I need help understanding is, as i believe in this piece of code here:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    ViewController *viewController = (__bridge ViewController*)inRefCon;
    viewController.indicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:alphaFloat];
```

This is where the UIView is being told to display varying intensities of red, what I want is to change that into a varying number.

The RMS to dBSPL value isn't a problem, its getting it displayed as continuously changing value in the place of the red box within the running app that I could really do with some help on, all help is incredibly appreciated in advance!

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you want to display is in the variable alphaFloat. You need to add a UILabel property to your ViewController, you could call it dBSPLView. Then in that place where viewController.indicatorView.backgroundColor is being changed you would do something like this:

```
viewController.dBSPLView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", alphaFloat];
```