# How to detect max dB Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to detect dB on a iOS Device, however, I am new to AV audio foundation can't really get to figure it out. I have come across this post: [iOS - Detect Blow into Mic and convert the results! (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230854/ios-detect-blow-into-mic-and-convert-the-results-swift), but it is not working for me.

My current code is this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreAudio

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!
var levelTimer = NSTimer()
var lowPassResults: Double = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //make an AudioSession, set it to PlayAndRecord and make it active
    var audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: nil)
    audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)

    //set up the URL for the audio file
    var documents: AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,  NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    var str =  documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent("recordTest.caf")
    var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(str as String)

    // make a dictionary to hold the recording settings so we can instantiate our AVAudioRecorder
    var recordSettings: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [AVFormatIDKey:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4,
                                                  AVSampleRateKey:44100.0,
                                                  AVNumberOfChannelsKey:2,AVEncoderBitRateKey:12800,
                                                  AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:16,
                                                  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue

    ]

    //declare a variable to store the returned error if we have a problem instantiating our AVAudioRecorder
    var error: NSError?

    //Instantiate an AVAudioRecorder
    recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL:url, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)
    //If there's an error, print otherwise, run prepareToRecord and meteringEnabled to turn on metering (must be run in that order)
    if let e = error {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        recorder.prepareToRecord()
        recorder.meteringEnabled = true

        //start recording
        recorder.record()

        //instantiate a timer to be called with whatever frequency we want to grab metering values
        self.levelTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.02, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.levelTimerCallback), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

}

//This selector/function is called every time our timer (levelTime) fires
func levelTimerCallback() {
    //we have to update meters before we can get the metering values
    recorder.updateMeters()

    //print to the console if we are beyond a threshold value. Here I've used -7
    if recorder.averagePowerForChannel(0) > -7 {
        print("Dis be da level I'm hearin' you in dat mic ")
        print(recorder.averagePowerForChannel(0))
        print("Do the thing I want, mofo")
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i was currently building my app about movie making,and learned something about how to metering sound level in dB.

the origin data of **recorder.averagePowerForChannel** is not really dB level of the sound,it's provide a level range which is **-160 - 0**,so we need some modification to make this data more reasonable

so i was finding some thing that makes this data(value) convert to dB level data.

(Sorry about forgot where i was found it!)

here is the code

```
/**
 Format dBFS to dB

 - author: RÅGE_Devil_Jåmeson
 - date: (2016-07-13) 20:07:03

 - parameter dBFSValue: raw value of averagePowerOfChannel

 - returns: formatted value
 */
func dBFS_convertTo_dB (dBFSValue: Float) -> Float
{
var level:Float = 0.0
let peak_bottom:Float = -60.0 // dBFS -> -160..0   so it can be -80 or -60

if dBFSValue < peak_bottom
{
    level = 0.0
}
else if dBFSValue >= 0.0
{
    level = 1.0
}
else
{
    let root:Float              =   2.0
    let minAmp:Float            =   powf(10.0, 0.05 * peak_bottom)
    let inverseAmpRange:Float   =   1.0 / (1.0 - minAmp)
    let amp:Float               =   powf(10.0, 0.05 * dBFSValue)
    let adjAmp:Float            =   (amp - minAmp) * inverseAmpRange

    level = powf(adjAmp, 1.0 / root)
}
return level
}
```

i was noticed that you are recording whit 2 channels so it will be little different with my code;

wish could help you out or give you some ideas :D

*LAST UPDATE*

Change coding language to swift

Comment: Oh, by the way, `averagePowerForChannel` *does* return decibels. They go from -160 to 0 because they are [dbFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS). -160 means silence, and it goes all the way *up* to 0 which is full level.

Comment: oh,thx about the language mention(and wiki of course :) ). i'll try to rewrite my answer's code in swift and modified my answer asap.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @EricAya From what I understood, dbFS values are relative to the mic's own maximum saturation (0dBFS). This value is relative to a mic's properties, shouldn't it actually be impossible to convert that to dB(a)? (unless you have a reference table for each microphone containing their own calibration details)

Comment: @itMaxence No, dbFS are not relative to mic properties, they represent an absolute value. Your mic has its own dynamic range, sure, and it's unlikely to be 160db, most of the times it will be around 80db for good mics, it depends on the mic's quality. But this range could be reproduced anywhere in the dbFS scale depending on the volume you bring the mic output to via an amplifier/recorder/etc. So it could be between 0dbFS and -80dbFs, or between -80dbFS and -160dbFS, or between -40dbFS and -120dbFS, etc.

Comment: These precisions help me thanks! But I'll maybe post a new question on SO to clear up some points related to what data I retrieve and what I'd like to convert it to~

Answer (score 1):

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation
    import CoreAudio

    class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

    
    let kRecordAudioFile = "myRecord.caf"
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    var timer: Timer?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var record: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stop: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var audioPower: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var powerLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var maxPowerLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var powerLbl: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setAudioSession()
        if !(audioRecorderr?.isRecording ?? false) {
             audioRecorderr?.record()
            timerr?.fireDate = Date.distantPast
         }
    }

        
    func setAudioSession() {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        do {
            // Set to play and record state, so that the recording can be played after recording
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to set audio session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    
    func getSavePath() -> URL? {
        guard let urlStr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr).appendingPathComponent(kRecordAudioFile)
        print("file path: \(url.path)")
        
        return url
    }

    func getAudioSetting() -> [String: Any] {
        var settings: [String: Any] = [:]
        
        settings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
        settings[AVSampleRateKey] = 8000
        settings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2
        settings[AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey] = 8
        settings[AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey] = true
        settings[AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey] = AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        
        return settings
    }

    
    var audioRecorderr: AVAudioRecorder? {
        if audioRecorder == nil {
            // route
            guard let url = getSavePath() else {
                return nil
            }
            
            // recording settings
            let settings = getAudioSetting()
            
            // create recorder
            do {
                audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: url, settings: settings)
                audioRecorder?.delegate = self
                audioRecorder?.isMeteringEnabled = true
            } catch {
                print("Failed to create audio recorder: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        return audioRecorder
    }

    
    var timerr: Timer? {
        if timer == nil {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self, selector: #selector(audioPowerChange), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        return timer
    }

    
    @objc func audioPowerChange() {
        self.audioRecorderr?.updateMeters() //update measurements
        let power = self.audioRecorderr?.averagePower(forChannel: 0) ?? 0.0
        let powerMax = self.audioRecorderr?.peakPower(forChannel: 0) ?? 0.0
        print("power = \(power), powerMax = \(powerMax)")
        
        let progress = (1.0 / 160.0) * (power + 160.0)
        
        let adjustedPower = power + 155 - 50
        
        var dB = 0
        if adjustedPower < 0.0 {
            dB = 0
        } else if adjustedPower < 40.0 {
            dB = Int(adjustedPower * 0.875)
        } else if adjustedPower < 100.0 {
            dB = Int(adjustedPower - 15)
        } else if adjustedPower < 110.0 {
            dB = Int(adjustedPower * 2.5 - 165)
        } else {
            dB = 110
        }
        
        self.powerLbl.text = "averagePower = \(abs(power))"
        self.maxPowerLbl.text = "peakPower = \(abs(powerMax))"
        self.powerLabel.text = "\(dB)dB"
        self.audioPower.setProgress(Float(progress), animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: - UI Events
    
    @IBAction func recordClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
     
    }
    
    @IBAction func pauseClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if audioRecorderr?.isRecording ?? false {
            audioRecorderr?.pause()
            timerr?.fireDate = Date.distantFuture
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func resumeClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        recordClick(sender)
    }
    
    @IBAction func stopClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        audioRecorderr?.stop()
        timerr?.fireDate = Date.distantFuture
        audioPower.progress = 0.0
    }
    
    // MARK: - Recorder proxy method
    
    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if !(audioPlayer?.isPlaying ?? false) {
            audioPlayer?.play()
        }
        print("Recording complete!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have spend 2 days on internet to find the code that's accurately generate the decibel value, this code works perfectly and its value match with the noise app provided by apple.